# How to check if event click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code to add tags by pressing enter (which):

```
Start.StartPostModal = TD.Views.Modal_Box.extend({
    events: {
        'keypress input#post_tags'  : 'onAddTags',
    },

    /**
     * add tags
     */
    addTags: function(tags) {

    },

    /**
     * catch event user enter in tax input
     */
    onAddTags: function(event) {
        var val = $(event.currentTarget).val();
        console.log('keypress');
        if (event.which == 13) {
            this.addTags(val);
        }
        return event.which != 13;
    }
});
```

How can make it working by clicking a button? I add the event click and try many solutions but failed.

Comment: Are you using a library? It seems like there are some details missing. What button do you want to click. What are you actually trying to do? Run addTags on click?

Comment: @JamesGanong if you check the events you will find that if i keypress enter so add new tag i need to add new event if clicked on button so also add the tag.

Comment: People are down-voting your question because you haven't given enough information (code) to give you an answer. Please consider updating the question with as much relevant information as possible so that we can help you. Just wanted to let you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit unclear how it works currently. So, I'm making a bunch of assumptions here, but here's an idea:

```
Start.StartPostModal = TD.Views.Modal_Box.extend({
    events: {
        'keypress input#post_tags'  : 'onAddTags',
        'click #myButton' : 'onAddTagsClick',
    },

    /**
     * add tags
     */
    addTags: function(tags) {

    },

    /**
     * catch event user enter in tax input
     */
    onAddTags: function(event) {
        var val = $(event.currentTarget).val();
        console.log('keypress');
        if (event.which == 13) {
            this.addTags(val);
        }
        return event.which != 13;
    },

    onAddTagsClick: function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      this.addTags($('input#post_tags').val());
    }

});
```

Assumptions:

- the button to click has an id of `myButton`
- you want to run `addTags` with the value of the `input` with id `post_tags`
- `onAddTagsClick` doesn't need to return anything based on the library/plugin/module being used.
- you can add events to this in the way I'm assuming...